# MySQL - Lock Table Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anybody help me (by providing SQL query) how can I lock a database table thus nobody can read, write or update ( If possible !) ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: @MitchWheat, I want this because in my application, I want a user face problems with dirty read and dirty write. I am trying to solve by shared mode and exclusive mode lock, however it creates problems regarding deadlock.

Comment: afaik you can not prevent sessions to read from a table (not in MySQL anyway, except for by removing privileges or shutting down mysqld.

Comment: @TheNail you're right - but he can do it on the application level

Comment: I solve it by using mutex in process level. Because, other ways seem little bit nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick and dirty:
when you want it locked - rename the table:

```
RENAME TABLE old_table TO backup_table
```

and after you're done - rename it back:

```
RENAME TABLE backup_table TO old_table
```

of course that you'll have to catch errors on your Application and handle "Table 'tbl_name' doesn't exist" as "access denied".

Comment: You are telling nothing about what to do if the table is being accessed *at* the time of renaming. I mean, you wouldn't be able to rename it then, would you?

Comment: a "select" won't harm - the only race condition possible is if two threads try to rename it simultaneously - but you can handle it easily by synchronizing the method that renames the table.

Comment: Right, but I was actually talking about write accessing, like with an UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE. The OP wants to block any kind of access, including write access, which means it (write access) is possible, which means someone might be in the middle of writing just when the RENAME statement was issued.